# Найти значение в строке Java

Tags: java, строки

Предположим что у нас есть текстовик, в котором текст вида:
Number = 1
Vasya
Number = 2
Valera
Number = 3
Kolya

Нужно перевести текст в строку(это не проблема) и найти все номера, желательно только те что идут после "Number = ", и записать в переменные/массив, не суть, перешерстил гугл, ниче не нашел(мб я тупой).
Помогите, как решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать следующее:

1. Делим всю строку, используя `"Number = "` как разделитель.
2. В каждой получившейся подстроке вида `"1 Vasya"` забираем часть до пробела и преобразовываем ее к `Integer`.
3. Складываем это все в массив.

Код:

```
// Наш текст
String text = "Number = 1 Vasya Number = 2 Valera Number = 3 Kolya";

// Делим его, используя разделитель
String substrings[] = text.split("Number\\s*=\\s*");

// Создаем пустую коллекцию
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

// Проходимся по получившимся подстрокам
for (int i = 1; i < substrings.length; ++i) {
    String str = substrings[i];
    arrayList.add(new Integer(str.substring(0, str.indexOf(' '))));
}

// Выводим arrayList на экран
arrayList.forEach(System.out::println);

// Если нужно после создать массив примитивов:
int numbers[] = new int[arrayList.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
    numbers[i] = arrayList.get(i);
}
```

Я использовал в качестве разделителя `"Number\\s*=\\s*"` для того, чтобы все работало, даже если у вас перед знаком `=` или после не стоит пробелов, или же стоит их несколько.

Вот тут вот:

```
new Integer(str.substring(0, str.indexOf(' ')))
```

Мы берем одну из подстрок, и "выдираем" из нее часть с самого начала и до первого пробела. После создаем экземпляр `Integer`, используя конструктор, принимающий строку как параметр.

Проходимся же в цикле мы начиная с подстроки `1`, т.к. нулевая будет либо пустой, либо содержать текст, предшествующий нужным нам `Number...`.

И еще. Если вы хотите сделать что-то более универсальное, чтобы находить такие вхождения в разных местах произвольного текста, то вам нужно использовать более сложные регулярные выражения, которые вам вряд ли кто-то просто возьмет и напишет. Так что изучайте теорию про регулярки...

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.company;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        //текстовик
        File file = new File("C:\\text.txt");

        //строка
        String s = "";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        while (sc.hasNext())
            String s=sc.next();

        //разделитель
        String i = "Number = ";

        //массив
        List<String> array = new ArrayList<>();

        //Собственно алгоритм
        while (s.contains(i)) {
            array.add(""+s.charAt(s.indexOf(i) + i.length()));
            s = s.substring(s.indexOf(i)+i.length()+1);
        }

        //вывод массива
        System.out.println(array);
    }
}
```